# Is it possible to use type hint validation directly?

Tags: python, types

With version 3.6 python has type hints:

```
from typing import List, Union

def foo() -> List[Union[str, int]]:
    return 3
```

However can we use this syntax outside of intended scope?
i.e. Can we use this syntax to validate some object?

```
objects = [['foo', 1], ['bar', 2.2]]
for object in objects:
    if not isinstance(object, List[Union[str, int]]):
        print(f'error, invalid object: {object}')
```

Comment: There's no validation even in the situations you were aware you could use type hints.

Comment: Also, `List[str, int]` is an invalid way to use `List`.

Comment: how do you see validating of potentially infinite iterator with type hint like `Iterator[str]`?

Comment: @user2357112 you're right, changed it to `List[Union[str, int]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the [`typeguard` module](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard):

```
from typeguard import check_type
from typing import Tuple
objects = [('foo', 1), ('bar', 2.2)]
for object in objects:
    try:
        check_type('object', object, Tuple[str, int])
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
```

This outputs:

```
type of object[1] must be int; got float instead
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I'm surprised there's no built-in alternative though.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Well the `typeguard` module is implemented in pure Python, so technically speaking there's a built-in alternative, namely to implement what `typeguard` implements yourself.